# How to upload bufferedImage without storing it in user's system?

Tags: java, php, swing

I am a beginner in java, and I am trying to write a simple screen-capture program. I wrote a simple `SWING` desktop app with a button and a text-field, and what I am trying to do is, when a user clicks that button the app takes a snapshot of the screen using `awt.Robot`, and sends that image and the text to a PHP script on my server.

My snapshot function so far is:

```
private void takeSnapShot(){
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
            //Try to save the captured image
            try {
                File file = new File("screenshot_full.png");
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it's fairly simple so far, however I am not sure how to send that image to my PHP script without actually storing the image on user's PC.

Oh and I am using `apache httpClient` library for communicating to the web server. For the text I guess I can pass it in the URL as a get query, but I am not sure what to do about the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To slightly modify your existing method, perhaps you could use a temporarily file and then delete it when you are finished with it. Perhaps it might look something like:

```
private void takeSnapShot(){
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle area = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
        //Try to save the captured image
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()), ".png");
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
            //send image
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to construct an `int[][]` from your `BufferedImage` which will hold the RGB values for every pixel of the image:

```
public int[][] getColors(final BufferedImage image){
    assert image != null;
    final int[][] colors = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
    for(int x = 0; x < colors.length; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < colors[x].length; y++)
            colors[x][x] = image.getRGB(x, y);
    return colors;
}
```

I am a little unsure about what you hope to achieve; What do you plan on doing with the image?

Answer (score 2):

`ImageIO.write` can to an `OutputStream` of your choice.

So if you don't want to write the image to a `File`, you can simply write it to a different stream instead...

For example...

```
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Rectangle area = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
    //Try to save the captured image
    try {
        os = ...;
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }
    }
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ScrCaptFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Of course, I have no idea where you're sending the data, so you'll need to define the `OutputStream` yourself.

If you have the memory for it, you could write it a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then write this to whatever output stream you need in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make this a WebsService and let your PHP consume it? You could send the binary data through the WebsService using some sort of Base64 encoder.

You could do this to get the bytes of the BufferedImage:

```
byte[] binaryData = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```